# RDkit fingerprint

Tags: polymer, fingerprint, rdkit

> I have 100 polymers and I want to compare their solubility by their fingerprint.

> > By using rdkit I reach a list of bits for each polymer like as [39, 80, 152, 233, 234, 265, 310, 314, 321, 356, 360, 406, 547, 650, 662, 726, 730, 801, 819, 849, 935]', but I faced with this error: " it could not convert string to float: "

my first question is how can I reach to just one bit for each polymer?
and how can I define each bit as a single feature in rdkit?

Comment: Fingerprints for a molecule are vectors. They can't be converted into a single number. For example, a sample ECFP fingerprint can be like [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, ......so on]. As you can see, it's a vector, it can't be represented into a single value.

Comment: thanks!
so I am wondering if you can tell me your opinion about how can I compare all my polymers by their fingerprints?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your problem, I believe you use Morgan Fingerprint with radius=2 and fpSize=1024. However, count fingerprint results in a list of hashed value.
If you want to deal with comparison, I suggested you should use `rdkit.Chem.rdMolDescriptors.GetMorganFingerprintAsBitVect` in here #1.

If you want to use count fingerprint, see here #2 and search this query: `The types of atom pairs and torsions are normal (default), hashed and bit vector (bv). The types of the Morgan fingerprint are bit vector (bv, default) and count vector (count).`

If you want to get the result as `np.array`, you can run `bv = GetMorganFingerprintAsBitVect(mol, radius=your_radius, nBits=1024, *args, **kwargs).ToBitString()`, then run `np.frombuffer(bv.encode(), dtype=np.uint8) - 48`

However, I cannot provide explicit description and solution without the code so please provide it for further support. Thank you.

#1: https://www.rdkit.org/docs/source/rdkit.Chem.rdMolDescriptors.html?highlight=getmorganfingerprintasbitvect#rdkit.Chem.rdMolDescriptors.GetMorganFingerprintAsBitVect

#2: https://www.rdkit.org/docs/GettingStartedInPython.html

Comment: If you want to get the result as `np.array`, you can run `bv = GetMorganFingerprintAsBitVect(mol, radius=your_radius, nBits=1024, *args, **kwargs).ToBitString()`, then run `np.frombuffer(bv.encode(), dtype=np.uint8) - 48`